# GoogleScript | I am receiving ReferenceError: recipient is not defined when indicating recipient email with "jared@jaredgibb.xyz"

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am creating an API POST call with Thunkable.com. I am attempting to 'call' into my googlescript. I followed a tutorial but am receiving this error in the response

```
ReferenceError: recipient is not defined
```

Screenshot of the error message in googlescript

[Google Script and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwGHJ.png)

and here is my script

```
function doPost(e) 
{
  var message = e.parameters.message;
  message = JSON.stringify(message);
  var subject = e.parameters.subject;
  subject = JSON.stringify(subject);

  MailApp.sendEmail("Jared@jaredgibb.xyz", subject, message);
}
```

and the URL I am calling

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxR4u7EENQFUFmmtC-VtVZGymCs4mDjqkudaLxJ1lG4IqHaOcU/exec

and here are my blocks I use to make the API call

[My Thunkable Block Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiWgP.png)

I can't get any messages to send. any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, when the Web Apps is redeploy as new version, what result will you get? Because when the script of Web APps was modified, when the Web Apps is not redeployed as new version, the latest script is not reflected to the Web Apps. I was worried about this.

Comment: I visited your script link and got a `cript function not found: doGet` error. Have you saved your script and deployed it as a new version under the `Publish > Deploy as web app` menu item?

Comment: @Tanaike and Rafa-Guillermo, thank you for your responses. I have saved and published this various times. That was my first thought. Howver, even after saving the script and waiting 5 minutes, I receive the same error.

The idea would be that I could pass the message and subject to the script using a API POST call using that URL and passing along the message and subject as parameters of a JSON object

Comment: Actually @Tanaike, I think you proposal was the solution. I am not sure how to mark it as the solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When the script for Web Apps is modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)